# How to populate test suite names as headers in junit-noframes.html

Tags: junit, ant, jasmine, karma-jasmine

We have an ant build file running jasmine unit tests

```
<parallel>
    <antcall target="-test-base-jasmine-unit">
        <param name="karma-conf-file" value="test1.conf.js" />
    </antcall>
    <antcall target="-test-base-jasmine-unit">
        <param name="karma-conf-file" value="test2.conf.js" />
    </antcall>
....
```

and outputting a report junit-noframes.html.

In the report, each separate target conf file is in it's own section, with a header at the top.

Our headers all display 'TestCase 0)'
[Current State: all 0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVV6p.png)
I would like them to display some unique identifier instead of the 0) like in this found example. [Each target has descriptive name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFNZ0.png)

I haven't found anything in the documentation. I've tried adding likely sounding params but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: "Likely sounding params"? What's going on in your `-test-base-jasmine-unit` target? That will have all the params that you're setting.

Comment: -test-base-jasmine-unit just calls karma.cmd with the karma-conf-file param. I tried adding params like name="description" but that was just a wild stab in the dark.